# Angular ng-hide is not working in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
return {
restrict : "AC",
template : + '<div> '
+ '     <span class="smallFont" data-ng-hide="dossierItem.itemDetail.pubdate">{{ item.createdOn | hbdatetime }}</span>'
+ '     <span class="smallFont" data-ng-show="dossierItem.itemDetail.pubdate">{{ item.itemDetail.pubdate | hbdatetimepubdate }}</span>'
+ ' </div>',
link : function(scope, elm, attrs) {
scope.$watch(attrs.itemList, function(value) {
elm.text(value);
});
}
```

I can see both dates are loading in the inspect element.But it is always showing create date on the view.
I am showing a detailed info while clicking on this ,if i do that it will display the correct one in both places .

But not sure why ng-hide is not working in directive .

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z45wk/1/)

Problem here you miss open `div` tag in template portion and make sure assign value before need to create/initialize object.

```
    $scope.dossierItem = {};
    $scope.dossierItem.itemDetail = {};
    $scope.dossierItem.itemDetail.pubdate = new Date();
```

This cause issue:

```
$scope.dossierItem.itemDetail.pubdate = new Date();
```

if not initialize `dossierItem` object it throws errors. Please your console error to inspect better. Few things eliminated for clarity.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

myApp.controller("MainCtrl",function($scope){

    $scope.dossierItem = {};
    $scope.dossierItem.itemDetail = {};
    $scope.dossierItem.itemDetail.pubdate = new Date();

    $scope.validDate = true;

    $scope.item= {},
    $scope.item.createdOn = new Date();

    console.log($scope.dossierItem);
});


myApp.directive("test", function(){

return {
restrict : "AC",
template :'<div>'
    +'<span class="smallFont" ng-hide="dossierItem.itemDetail.pubdate">span1 {{item.createdOn}} </span>'
    +'<span class="smallFont" ng-show="dossierItem.itemDetail.pubdate">span2 {{item.createdOn}}</span>'
+'</div>',
}
});
```